# Angular slow load because of font

Tags: angular

In my deployed application, the load times are insanely high, and the thing that takes the most time to load are the fonts.

[Network tab of the Developers tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQwAi.png)

Is there a way to make this times shorter? The fonts are inside the project in the assets folder. Can I preload them in the head tag or add them to the angular.json in any way so it takes less for them to load?

Edit: I forgot to say that when I serve the app in local the fonts load just fine.

Comment: What's the font? Where are you downloading it from? Is it on your server?

Comment: maybe serve them faster and not 500bps ;)

Comment: @CristianTraìna the font is inside the project, served within the assets folder

Comment: @Antoniossss how can I check that? Or does this have something to do with the server the app is hosted in?

Comment: Since all t he time is consumed by data transfer, either you are serving 1gb  of fonts, or you have low bandwidth.